# Проверить шаблоны на наличие отсутствующих css, js файлов

Tags: linux

Хотелось бы в автоматическом режиме проверять что в проекте присутствуют все необходимые файлы (.js, .css, images, fonts).

Имеется php curl-парсер, который парсит bootstrap-шаблоны и сохраняет локально все html файлы и все ресурсы, которые там инклудятся (насколько может). Преобразуя пути `<img src="">`, `<script src="">` `<link href="">` в относительные. На выходе получается набор html файлов:

- index.html
- profile.html
- login.html
- 404.html
- и т.д.

И набор css, js, images, fonts:

- assets/jss/*
- assets/js/*
- assets/images/*

Проблема в том, что парсер что то да упускает. Например, внутри font-awesome.css инклудятся еще дополнительные файлы:
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

```
'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.5.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.5.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0')
```

Парсер их не кравлит. Где то может какие то картинки упустить.

После того, как парсер отработал, я вручную пробегаюсь по всем страницам темы и смотрю как выглядят страницы и есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера.

Как можно это автоматизировать? Автоматически находить битые ссылки? Например, когда css подгружается внутри другой css или как в примере с font-awesome.

Я это представляю так: даём на вход index.html. Далее кто то (**эмулятор браузера**) рендерит страницу, загружает все ресурсы, проходит по всем ссылкам и тоже рендерит. И выдаёт какие ресурсы не смог загрузить. Под linux`ом всё.

Comment: "Парсер их не кравлит." а по-русски это?

Comment: @edem, «собирает».

Comment: @jekabi интересно, а причём здесь метка [linux]. я бы пошел в сторону составления чек-листа по которому связка find+xargs+grep будет сверчт проект